# Does going to the other side of Milky Way galaxy mean seeing different observable universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, observable-universe, milky-way

What if there was a robot that got sent to the other side of the Milky Way by just traveling with a fusion engine and started orbiting a planet that has around Earth's gravity in order to avoid any time dialation problem, and then started scanning the CMB and the universe from there and then the robot traveled that distance back to Earth and then the picture is compared to the picture we have from Earth regarding how the universe looks? Would they be the same or different? Can this prove that there is more stuff outside the observable universe that we see on Earth?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the observable universe is growing at the speed of light, as more and more light is able to reach us over time. If you sent a probe to some distant location, it would indeed see a slightly different observable universe. But if it were to transmit that information back to you, by the time you received it, your observable universe would have already grown to include the entirety of the probe's at the time of transmission.

A more concrete way to see this is to think about the cosmic microwave background light coming from the probe's direction. The probe receives it before you do. However, if the probe tells you what it sees, its signal cannot reach you before the same cosmic background light also does.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you took account of the journey time (hundreds of thousands of years) then the CMB would look the same from the other side of our galaxy as it does from Earth. The size of our galaxy is minute compared to the distance that the CMB radiation has travelled. It is rather like asking does a mountain many kilometres away look different if I move one metre to my left.

Comment: How about going to Andromeda Galaxy? Does that affect anything because Andromeda is orders of magnitude farther away right because that is on the order of millions of light years away as opposed to something like a 100 thousand light years.